# Pip can't install flask-socketio

Tags: python, pip

I want to install the module flask-socketio using pip2, however I get an error, that no matching bidict version was found. I looked bidict up, and it turns out,  that the version doesnt even exist. I tried installing some other packets, but nothing worked. Here you can see the full error

'''
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement bidict>=0.21.0 (from python-socketio>=5.0.2->flask-socketio) (from versions: 0.1.5, 0.2.1, 0.3.0, 0.3.1, 0.9.0rc0, 0.9.0.post1, 0.10.0, 0.10.0.post1, 0.11.0, 0.12.0.post1, 0.13.0, 0.13.1, 0.14.0, 0.14.1, 0.14.2, 0.15.0.dev0, 0.15.0.dev1, 0.15.0rc1, 0.15.0, 0.16.0, 0.17.0, 0.17.1, 0.17.2, 0.17.3, 0.17.4, 0.17.5, 0.18.0, 0.18.1, 0.18.2, 0.18.3, 0.18.4)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for bidict>=0.21.0 (from python-socketio>=5.0.2->flask-socketio)
'''

Any Ideas?

Comment: Per https://pypi.org/project/bidict/ , version 0.18.3 is the last release that supports Python 2. Unless there's some reason you must use Python 2, the path forward is to use Python 3.

Answer (score 8):

`Flask-SocketIO` dropped support for Python 2 at version 5.0.0. Install an older version:

```
pip install "Flask-SocketIO<5.0.0"
```

Answer (score 2):

This solved the problem on my Raspberry Pi:

```
pip3 install flask-socketio
```